# Which countries will get mostly affected by brexit because of economical issues if brexit is decided to happen?

Tags: brexit

There are a lot of countries (especially in Europe) that trade with Britain so some changes are believed to happen if Brexit is decided.
What countries will get affected by Brexit the most and why?

Comment: Brexit has been decided. There was referendum to leave and Article 50 has been invoked. As to what will happen in the future, do you mean economically? Socially? Diplomatically? Something else entirely? I don't know how anyone can predict this.

Comment: @ouflak in case of a no-deal brexit it's actually pretty easy: The Netherlands. Economically they suffer from loss of trade and companies will have to adapt (not aimed at selling goods outside the SM, yet). Diplomatically they lose in the EU because they lost a strong ally at the table.

Comment: @JJJ, Then borrow some money, sell short those companies that will be most affected in the future by issues in the Netherlands, and make a fortune! Think I'll hold off on that myself though.... There's just too many possibilities.

Comment: France and Ireland are the obvious candidates; Calais is going to get even more unmanageable, and some as yet unknown change will happen to the Irish border.

Answer (score 2):

- *Most affected:* The UK.
- *Second most affected:* Ireland. There is the whole Northern Ireland issue, plus the problems the Irish economy will get if they have difficulty trading with the UK or transiting through the UK.
- *Also affected:*

  - France, Belgium, Netherlands. Traffic jams on the way to the border crossings, reduced trade.
  - Spain. Lots of Brits living there become foreigners. Some may decide to sell properties instead of going through a residency permit process.
  - Poland. Lots of Poles have found work in the UK, they would not get work permits quite as easily.
- *Everyone in the Eurozone:* Ireland could face a recession. They were vulnerable during the 2007-2008 financial crisis.
- *Everyone in the EU27:* In addition to those above, a reduction in trade and industry could hit everybody. Perhaps only a few [basis points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_point), perhaps more.